# How to interface multiple RF transmitters with single RF receiver?

Tags: 433mhz

How do I receive multiple signals simultaneously at a single receiver (433MHz) with multiple transmitters ? I am working on a polling system. This one is similar to the audience poll system using clicker devices.

Comment: Two or more transmissions sent simultaneously on the same channel the receiver is tuned to cannot be decoded. That's your main problem.

Comment: How about using delay system ? How can I implement the concept of TDMA for RF ?

Comment: Use a transceiver or, by some other means, trigger all transmitters (to synchronize them) so they can each (in turn) send a transmission based on a unique address internally stored. The address determines the delay from the sync-trigger-point.

Comment: So basically I would need to program every transmitter remote using a microcontroller ? I plan to use around 50 such clickers fitter with basic RF transmitter.

Comment: Your main problem still stands - you have to find a way of synchronizing all the transmitters OR you use a transceiver in each "clicker device" and poll (from the master) each "clicker device" to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a receiver by each transmitter. If the receiver detects any signal, it inhibits the transmitter, but is interlocked with the transmitter so that it does not respond to a signal from it. The lockout period should be set to be different for each transmitter/receiver pair. So, if any transmitter detects that another unit is transmitting, it waits a fixed period before it tries to transmit. Since the wait periods are different for each transmitter, after any unit transmits, the waiting unit with the shortest disable time will be next to transmit, and so on.